# SailsJs call function into the same controller

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I want to call a function in the same controller but I mostly have an error like: "ReferenceError: myFunctionB is not defined"

```
module.exports = {

    myfunctionA: function(req, res){

        var theword;
        theword = myFunctionB({id:26})

        return res.json({say:theword})

    }, 

    myfunctionB: function(req, res){

        var id = req.param('id');

        niceword.get({
            id:id
        }, function(err, word){

            if(err){return res.negotiate(err);}
            if(!word){return res.json({err:"no word found"})}

            return res.json({word:word});

        })

    }

}
```

I also tryed by to put myFunctionB into a service but, as I use many other controller etc I have no response.. Any idea?

Comment: You can't do that. Or at least shouldnt. If you have to call the same function from several places, create a service

Comment: Thank for your ansere, I tryed to put in into a service but I had no response when I try to communicate with my database because of the interval or i don't realy know... ?

Comment: Yes, this function needs to have a callback or return a promise, since you will be doing async stuff inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  The proper way, as yBrodsky says, is to create a service that runs a callback or returns a promise:

```
myServiceFunctionB: function(params, cb) {
   var id = params.id;
   niceword.get({
        id:id
    }, function(err, word){
        return cb({ say: { word: word });
    });
}
```

And then in your controller, just use:

```
return MyServiceName.myServiceFunctionB({id: 26}, res.json);
```

You can also pass in your req and res to continue using those:

```
myServiceFunctionB: function(req, res) { ...
```

Alternatively, you can use the `this` keyword in your controller:

```
myfunctionA: function(req, res){
    req.params.id = 26;
    return this.myfunctionB(req, res);
}
```

If you'll be doing more complicated logic where context gets lost, just set a new var at the start using this:

```
myfunctionA: function(req, res){
    var self = this;
    req.params.id = 26;
    //...lots of nested promises or callbacks...
         return self.myfunctionB(req, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you yBrodsky and wwwslinge, I finaly get what I need thank of you.

I had to make a little change because I still need to use the data after they pass into the function.

Controller

```
MyServiceName.functionB({id:1}, function(data){

    // doing some stuff with the data and then
    return res.json({data: data});

});
```

Service

```
functionB: function(params, cb){

    var id = params.id;

    Niceword.getbyid({
        id:id
    }, function(err, word){

         if(err){return err}
         return cb({word:word});

    })

}
```